# Android Studio/Emulator on macOS with ARM CPU M1

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, hardware-acceleration, macos-big-sur

I started Android Studio `4.1` in macOS Big Sure `11.0.1` with new ARM cpu M1

After installing Rosetta: **Yes, it builds !**

But the Emulator has problems, it shows me ***CPU does not support VT-x***

Even ARM images have this issue [image]

I used the most recent, a very old api25 (Google has to do here something) but it's increadible slow

How to make the Emulator work and fast ?

Comment: Right now you won't be able to run the emulator since it uses Intel HAXM, which in turn uses Intel VT-x and Rosetta doesn't support virtualization. The fix has to come from the Android team to make it work with the M1 way of virtualization. :(

Comment: Exactly, I opened a Google ticket as well https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173624439 Ok, I understand for x86 but why it's for ARM images as well ?

Comment: Irrespective of Intel or ARM image, you need virtualization as it acts as a guest OS atop the host OS. The same reason why you can't run an x86 Linux image on a running x86 macOS or x86 Windows without using Parallels or VMWare!

Comment: A good read on emulation vs virtualization -- https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/7952/whats-the-difference-between-virtualization-and-emulation-why-it-matters/

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator?authuser=1#emulator_for_arm64_hosts here is a sentence "Support for Apple Silicon is in progress."

Comment: I hope they release soon as I ended up buying the M1 Mac. :)

Comment: Has anyone had success with emulators running API < 29? I'm able to create them but the emulator screen is entirely black.

Comment: @masterwok api25 is complete black on my machine too

Comment: @masterwok API 24 is all black for me too

Answer (score 313, accepted):

Good news !

**Edit on 28th of July 2021**

> Apple Silicon M1 Support

Now, there is an **arm64** release version available for **Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1)**
You can download it from here https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads

**Easy fix to use right architecture**

Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools (tab) -> Deselect 'Android Emulator' -> Ok

Now, when you try to run your app, or launch device from AVD Manager, it will give the 'Install Emulator' error -> Click Ok. This will automatically download the correct version.

**Use an arm64-v8a image !**

- Tools -> SDK Manager
- Install Android 11 (R) or 12.0 (S) and click Apply
- Tools -> AVD Manager -> click Create Virtual Device
- Choose any device that has the **Google Play Store** icon and click *Next*
- Choose an arm64-v8a on "Other Images" tab

[image: Android studio]

- When NDK runs into `Unknown host CPU architecture: arm64` you can solve it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69540773/1079990)
- <s>`kapt` [doesn't work](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/188693129)</s> Solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/68285501/1079990

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I have ordered an MBA and just wondering if it will be taxing enough to heat it up and throttle it..

Comment: I found a way to hear the ventilator for a long time with 100% CPU usage: just build one of this pull request local https://github.com/hannesa2/mediapipe/pull/7 With a normal Android studio usage it's max 50 CPU load

Comment: You mean it turns on the fan on your new Mac or the old Mac?

Comment: On the new one ! But this is the only task which turns it on

Comment: Got you! So by Android Studio usage you mean also the emulator, right?

Comment: Right. Open in Android Studio 5 apps at the same time, sync and build it, uses not more then 50 % This means the bottleneck is somewhere else

Comment: cool! thanks. Just wanted to know if the Macbook Air I ordered will have issues with running the emulator for long duration...

Comment: I also have a M1 Macbook Pro. I have been using qemu for arm64 on macos for months. It works but the performance really sucks. Why? Because qemu is software-layer emulating without hardware acceleration. But this is what we can have currently with the issue of lagging and unknown bugs. Only if once VM products supported the Apple Virtual Framework, we would experience smoothly.

Comment: My arm64-v8a Emulator is very fast, so qemu is a bad option

Comment: It seems your language must be English, otherwise you won't see the arm version

Comment: But , this is not the stable release isn't it? Can you use something like this this on production?

Comment: @JustCause A lot of stuff is working fast. Current this doesn't work: NDK, kapt (like Room)

Comment: @hannesach How about the SDK installation? Everything is okay there as usual? Because I'm using Android Studio only for the sake of having the SDK. My IDE is VS Code. Also when this is available in the stable channel, do you know whether you can directly update this or you have to do a fresh install?

Comment: @JustCause I see no issue with SDK installation, all is normal. But i don't use VS Code

Comment: @hannesach: Great. how is your exprience with the Google maps? Google say it is not working in iOS simulator yet, but works on real device.

Comment: Does july 27 update means that NDK projects is still not working? Thanks

Comment: @StayCool NDK still runs into `Unknown host CPU architecture: arm64` on my side. For this you need the x86 variant, there it works

Comment: @JustCause Sorry I missed  your Google maps question. Yes, it's working properly with M1

Comment: Can u please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68919616/android-studio-error-connection-react-native ?

Comment: It is still lagging when typing code and code completion... bad performance overall.

Comment: @Philip I only see it in x86 variant. Do you use right arm64 java ? You can choose it in preferences within Gradle settings

Comment: I deleted Android Studio and downloaded it again. I‘ve must have overlooked the option to download a Mac M1 x86+arm64 variant. When I had downloaded it before, it probably chose the Intel Version. I now have a little indicator inside the splash screen mentioning arm64 preview. Now code completion runs smoother overall.

Comment: BEWARE that even if it's working, you may find that the M1 version fails to install properly with the error "[An error occurred while trying to compute required packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69869181/error-about-android-studio-on-macbook-m1-an-error-occurred-while-trying-to-comp)." A workaround is available at that link.

Comment: Just wanna say thanks, you saved my day. I'm currently developing an android app on Macbook Pro M1 2020. And I constantly get crash while running Android Emulator.

Comment: These steps didn't work for me, unfortunately. The emulator process for AVD Nexus_5X_API_30 has terminated.

Comment: I am also facing the similar problem "the emulator process for avd pixel_4a_api_30 has terminated" while trying to use x86 or x86_64 images. But I can run arm-64 images just fine. Any idea about this?

Comment: @ImranurRahman Simply use arm-64 images

Comment: @hannesach In my case, I need to use an x86 or x86_64 system image to run a specific application.

Comment: This worked for me ! thanks a lot, I waste a lot of time trying to get the solution.

Answer (score 81):

This fixed my issue

Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools (tab) -> Deselect 'Android Emulator'
-> OK

Now, when you try to run your app, or launch device from AVD Manager, it will give the 'Install Emulator' error -> Click Ok. This will automatically download the correct version.

Comment: This was essential on my M1 Mac

Comment: Did not work for me on M1.

Comment: This has to be the correct solution. because major of developers who faced the issue because of transferring AN from Mac ( inter ) to M1 .. thanks for bring it up

Comment: This fixed the issue on my M1 mac. Thanks!

Comment: Fixed my issue on M1 mac. Thank you!

Comment: Work for me on M2

Answer (score 18):

I've had this problem with my new Macbook Pro M1 Pro (Macbook Pro 2021 14 Inch M1 Pro). after some digging around, the root of the problem was that I have transferred all my data from my old Mac (using Time Machine) which uses Intel (The other Mac is Macbook Pro 2011 13 Inch Intel), so other than a lot of apps which did not run or ran sluggishly and I had to reinstall their ARM version, the Android SDK Tools were transfered too.

So here are the simple steps to the solution:

1. Launch Android Studio
2. Select SDK Manager[image]
3. Go to SDK Tools tab[image]
4. Untick All the Packages, and keep them in your mind because you will retick them in the next step
5. You will have a dialog something like this, Select `Apply`. This way now you've uninstalled the old packages [image]
6. retick all packages (to reinstall their ARM version) and click apply, this may take some time depending on your internet speed as you are reinstalling all the packages
7. Try launching the emulator now, if the problem is not fixed, try restarting Android Studio or your laptop completely, My problem was fixed without restarting though

Comment: oh my god thank you so much, I was looking for a solution for hours. Had the exact same situation of transferring the data from my intel mac to the m1 mac. Thanks for the great solution!

Comment: @Moritz that's awesome, glad my efforts were not in vain

Comment: This works like a charm! Migrated from intel mac to M1 with time machine and had the same issue.

Comment: Thanks, it was an easy and good idea.

Answer (score 11):

If everything fails try this:

```
On Android Studio uncheck emulator -> tools -> Launch in a tool window
```

[image]

Got this from this official issue thread (by jeanlst):

https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview/issues/76#issuecomment-1023563846

Comment: Actually this resolved my Problem. Just to be clear, I had to **uncheck** this box to make my Emulators run again on a MacBook with the *Apple M1 Max* chip.

Answer (score 9):

I followed the steps that this guy talks and had good results: https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/my-journey-to-setup-android-emulator-for-m1-macbook-pro-b8365321b3e7

- Go to AVD Manager
- Click "+ Create Virtual Device"
- Choose a Device definition (ex. "Pixel 4a XL")
- Click "Next"
- Click "Other images"
- Download "S" System image
- Click "Next"
- Click "Finish"

Comment: I followed this too, but then I got stuck on the "Waiting for devices to come online.." error. Basically, my emulator works, and I can run my Gradle build, but then my app itself never runs on the emulator. After 300s, Android studio times out saying it can't find a device, and `add devices` shows my emulator as offline. Did you have something similar happen?

Comment: I am having same error.

Comment: I can see the system image names like 'S' 'R', what does those 'S' 'R' means?

Answer (score 7):

### Steps to run your Android APP on M1

Finally my Android APP running normally on my M1 chip !

**This presume you already have your environment variables set.**

1. Download **Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1)** [Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive)
   (I personally got the last I could *September 1, 2021*)
2. Install and open **Android Studio**
3. Tools -> SDK Manager
4. Check the box of **Android 12.0 (S)** and click ***Apply***

   ... Wait until it's downloaded
5. Tools -> AVD Manager -> click ***Create Virtual Device***
6. Choose any device that has the Play button and click ***Next***
7. Choose the image **S**. If you can't find it in the ***Recommended*** tab click on ***Other Images***
8. Final step click ***Next*** and ***Finish***

You should now be ready to go.

Comment: unknown error, 
Consider using an x86 system image on an x86 host for better emulation performance.

Answer (score 5):

**1. First, delete the android studio completely from your Mac system using the following command one by one:**

```
rm -Rf /Applications/Android\ Studio.app  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.android.*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/.AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/.gradle  
rm -Rf ~/.android  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Android*  
rm -Rf /usr/local/var/lib/android-sdk/
```

To delete all projects:

```
rm -Rf ~/AndroidStudioProjects
```

**2. Download the new Android studio using the below link:**

[https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads:~:text=android%2Dstudio%2D2021.2.1.15%2Dmac_arm.dmg](https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads:%7E:text=android%2Dstudio%2D2021.2.1.15%2Dmac_arm.dmg)

**3. Now install that software, create an emulator using arm version and open that emulator.**

Comment: I transferred to a new M2 mac from an Intel mac. When I first opened Android Studio it prompted me to install the ARM version. I did, but couldn't get any emulator to run, even after following the other tips in this thread. After completely uninstalling, as mentioned in this post, did the emulator finally run.

Answer (score 3):

You can now download the Android Studio Canary. In which you can run the android emulator with out any limitation of the android emulator m1 preview. In android emulator m1 preview there are issues with webview , device skin, sound etc..now you dont have to worry about that

Here is the link

https://developer.android.com/studio/preview?gclid=CjwKCAjwm7mEBhBsEiwA_of-TKIWfjv-MVe5W1Za_KcooZ-vfZ3vG_IkUyK40E-x10JLRRgnGjBCDBoCMOgQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: Yes, but after an update it stops working for me. In the meantime I did https://github.com/741g/android-emulator-m1-preview/issues/10#issuecomment-773545412 and now I'm able to use it seamless again

Comment: Oh, but its working fine for me. Previously with android emulator m1 preview i had issue with the webview and sound. But now its all fixed for me with this Android Studio Canary release

Answer (score 3):

as @Dipanker Shah reply, unclick the Android Emulator and run the AVD.
After that... android studio will pop a warning screen and press OK.
IDE will download the correct version.

Uncheck the Android Emulator and apply which will delete the existing files, and Recheck it and apply for new installation which will download compatible Android Emulator for M chips.
[image: 1]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Reinstalling the emulator via unticking/reticking was what got it to work for me! Thanks.

Comment: Success !! My Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1 faced the same issue with M1 Pro.  By Deleting (unchecking) existing Android emulator and reinstalling (by checking) solved the issue. Thank you @rraayy for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

For me I can run the emulator on my MacBook Pro MacOS Big Sur with ARM CPU M1 only on Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1 Beta03 and later versions) only after deleting **Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)**.

Comment: You definitely don't need HAXM on Apple Silicon. -Never-

Answer (score 2):

After I install the latest `AndroidStudioPreview` for Mac M1, it already included a default simulator with `arm64-v8a` ABI.
However, this simulator still not loaded by `AndroidStudio`

When I tried to run `adb` from Terminal, it shows `adb: command not found`. So I config the `adb`

- I set adb environment variable follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65538729)
- After that, when I run adb, I get the error `zsh: bad CPU type in executable`
- Then I fix it by `softwareupdate --install-rosetta` (follow [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/408379))
- Restart Terminal, then `adb` command working well
- Restart AndroidStudio, then it able to see and run app to simulator

Answer (score 1):

Now It's available

> **Apple Silicon Support**

**Android Studio Arctic Fox** **Canary 15** contains preliminary support for Apple Silicon (arm64). This version of Android Studio for this platform is still under active development, but we wanted to get a functional version out to the app developer community to get feedback. On top of the Intellij build, design tools work, and the **Android Emulator works with API 30 and API S** Developer Preview emulator system images.

[Click here to Download](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2021/04/android-studio-arctic-fox-canary-15.html)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with Android Studio 2020.3.1:

1. Tools -> AVD Manager -> click Create Virtual Device
2. Pick any one of the Hardware that **has Play Store**, e.g. Pixel 4
3. Click `Other Images` tab, download and select the S API Level
4. Click Next and Finish

Then you're good to go!

I don't have any issue so far with the performance of my emulator which is nice.

Source/Credit to author of: https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/my-journey-to-setup-android-emulator-for-m1-macbook-pro-b8365321b3e7

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer for M1 :

1. Uninstall Android studio
2. Delete all related files, check (Vikas Awate's answer @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/72564826/1489088) :

```
rm -Rf /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.android.*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/.AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/.gradle  
rm -Rf ~/.android  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Android*  
rm -Rf /usr/local/var/lib/android-sdk/
```

3. Re-install Android Studio Arctic Fox (check for the latest version here) : https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

Everything will work much better after that.
Inspired from crg's answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69088485/1489088

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear exactly what problems Google has had that they still have no way to release the M1 version. I got the DTK M1 almost a year ago. I think Google got it even earlier. Yes, there was a problem with emulation, but everything else in the IDE could definitely be done.

At least a loner did it without too much trouble. There is roughness, but the speed of work is different from sky and earth. Working with a regular Android Studio on M1 is almost impossible, and even with this refinement amateur, everything flies like lighting.

Here is the link:
https://github.com/dsa28s/android-studio-apple-m1

This is an unofficial canary version of Android Studio Arctic Fox with emulators on the Apple Silicon. I'm using it and it works well in most cases.

Comment: Did you read my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65176867/1079990 ? There is a link to aarch64 Beta4 included. All for M1

Comment: Yes, at last. :)

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio now has an official production release that supports the ARM chip. [2020.3.1.26](https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads)

Comment: It's since 28th July 2021. Please see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65176867/1079990

Comment: @hannesach - I'm sorry but your answer links to a non-production build

Answer (score 0):

For me none of the solutions worked.
Tried Arctic fox, bumblebee and etc.
The only thing that worked was the [Dolphin canary version](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview?gclid=Cj0KCQiAjJOQBhCkARIsAEKMtO1p5mGrpNMdi8oAZmjhcTbTA9qGE8KKC_bGicKPa1vLGsJidbgI_pYaAuucEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds).
As you install this version, it gives you a default emulator but it's also possible to create a new one without any issue.
Of course, there could be issues (because its canary ver.) but I'm happy that I can run something at this point.

Answer (score 0):

In the emulator window (when all emulator tabs are closed) click on "Update" link and update developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this Hack to manually install the emulator from the Dev Documentation
https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive

Comment: Which emulator did you install?

Answer (score 0):

When you have this problem now with an M1 or M2 Chip and you have transfered your android studio with the copy-functionality from an old Intel Mac, check that you also uninstall the Haxm-part of the emulator. This was my problem. In my case I also wasn't able to remove that easily,thats why I deleted everything from android studio on my Mac and reinstalled after that. Then everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to make sure to **select an arm compatible system image** (see screenshot below)

[image]