# Android Emulator not detected in Android Studio using the new M1 compatible emulator

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator, apple-m1

I can't run my flutter app on the new M1-optimized android emulator using android studio.

I followed this guide: https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/my-journey-to-setup-android-emulator-for-m1-macbook-pro-b8365321b3e7 [I used this emulator because I am using an M1 mac and it wont run other emulators]

But very time I open the emulator android studio won't detect the virtual device [It will open but I cant run my app on it].[Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9MhW.jpg)

Comment: I also have the same problem, any update?

Comment: Any resolution for this?!

Comment: same issue here, i've followed every solution out there and still nothing, only happens with android emulator

Answer (score 0):

Update: With the new Android Studio Artic Fox Canary 15
(https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2021/04/android-studio-arctic-fox-canary-15.html)  I can finally run the emulator with no problems!

Note: If you are using Homebrew as a package manager and tried updating android studio using the command 'brew update' it usually won't update to the arm version. Try uninstalling and installing it again.

For more information on setting up the arm emulator checkout this page: [Android Studio/Emulator on macOS with ARM CPU M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64907154/android-studio-emulator-on-macos-with-arm-cpu-m1)

For Update and info on M1 COMPATIBLE software you can check: https://isapplesiliconready.com/

[[image]