# InvocationTargetException with Android Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 arm64 on M1 Apple silicon

Tags: android, arm64, apple-m1, apple-silicon, kapt

During a build of my Android project on my M1 Apple Silicon using `kapt` (eg Room)

```
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Beta 1 arm64
..
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Beta 5 arm64
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Canary 2 aarch64
```

With

```
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Beta 5
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7360992, built on May 14, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 11.4
```

I run into

```
Execution failed for task ':FFTSpectrumLib:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I've no clue how to make it work with fast aarch64 !

With **x86** it works

```
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Beta 1 x86
```

Comment: Are you using Room database ?

Comment: Yes, I run into this using Room and Dagger. And I ask myself why I use this error prone and lifetime consuming Dagger

Comment: Yeah  , switch to hilt . It's way better . I have faced this issue many times and much of the times the issue is with the Room Dao or the entity or the annotation used in a wild way .And also , just a out of the way question . Does AS works good on M1 ? I am planning to buy one , but lack of supports makes me to back out .

Comment: Hilt that's new to me. Is it "better" then Koin ? Anyway, M1 works almost perfect, here you can read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64907154/android-studio-emulator-on-macos-with-arm-cpu-m1/65176867#65176867

Comment: Hilt is built by android team on top of dagger and it's awesome .It is easy to test as well .Also if you use ViewModel's then there is a dedicated way to inject dependencies ,so you don't have to perform the workaround . Should give a try .And thanks for the m1 reference .

Comment: My success comes too early, I changed my answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The root cause was Room `2.3.0`
This https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issues/450 pointed me to the solution

#### Solution A

add

`kapt "org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.34.0"`

it includes this https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/releases/tag/3.32.3.3

#### Solution B

Simply use Room `2.4.0-alpha03`