# Android Studio on new MacBook Pro with M1 Max Chip?

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

Is there some trick to get Android Studio running on the new M1 Max MacBook Pro? It does not matter which version I try, I always end up with "An error occurred while trying to compute required packages." when the Android Studio wants to install the SDK. Followed by "Failed to determine required packages".

Comment: Is this a useful link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64907154/android-studio-emulator-on-macos-with-arm-cpu-m1

Comment: This should work out of the box. I am able to install and run Android Studio on a M1 and M1 Pro based Macbook.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann if this would work out of the box, I would not have to ask...

Comment: @Capybara Yes and no. It would help if I would get this far. Android Studio already fails when it tries to fetch the SDK to install it. So I never get to the AVD part.

Comment: Not working for me either. I only get a "An error occurred while trying to compute required packages"

Comment: @Sebastian did you manage to solve this? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I have M1 Pro version of MacBook Pro. I got Android studio working in my MacBook by installing the 'Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1) Patch 3' version from the following link. I can currently run both Android projects and Flutter projects. Please share snapshot if you get any error.
https://developer.android.com/studio/archive