# How can I run older Android versions (e.g. API level 21) on emulators running on M1 Mac?

Tags: android, apple-m1

Though there is now an Android Studio for M1 macs and [Android emulator images which support arm architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64907154/android-studio-emulator-on-macos-with-arm-cpu-m1), these are only available for API level 30+. I want to run my application on an older version of Android to check for an issue locally on my mac.

I tried using the `armeabi-v7a`, but I just get `unable to find adb`. Note: other emulators are working fine. I also tried to find a way to launch Android Studio in Rosetta mode using `arch -x86_64 open -a /Users/zen/Applications/JetBrains\ Toolbox/Android\ Studio.app .`, but that didn't change anything. I have `adb` on my path, when running `which adb`, I get `/Users/zen/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb`.

Does anyone have **older versions of Android** running on emulators on M1 macs?

[image: Virtual device configuration window > System image > Other images tab]

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @JérémyReynaud, I use an old intel machine .