# Android - How to run *older* API images on M1 Mac

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-5.0-lollipop, apple-m1

I know there are a lot of questions about how to run the Android Studio emulator on M1 Macs. It works fine for newer API images (24 and above right now).

However, my project currently supports down to API level 21 (Lollipop), and I need to be able to run an emulator at that level to assess the product. Unfortunately, all API 21 images I've tried result in the emulator being killed immediately like what used to happen for all emulators on M1.

I'm pretty sure it's an M1 issue. Does anyone have solutions or ideas for working with those older emulator images?

Comment: Similar question posted here (also without any suggested answers): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70070274/how-can-i-run-older-android-versions-e-g-api-level-21-on-emulators-running-on

Comment: Shame no one seems to know. I hope this is on Google's radar. I'm a little surprised there aren't more questions about it.

Comment: We may be permanently out of luck: https://doist.dev/posts/how-to-use-x86-emulators-on-m1-macs