# Unable to open Android TV emulator on Mac M1 pro machine

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, apple-m1, android-tv

Android TV is not launching on Mac M1 pro. Getting *error* "emulator process for AVD  has terminated."
Recommended image and ARM image tab shows "No System images available to select" therefore selected other Image and got the above error message.

As per discussion in [Emulator on macOS with ARM CPU M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64907154/android-studio-emulator-on-macos-with-arm-cpu-m1) we have to choose arm64-v8a but for Android TV I do not see any images with v8a to select.
Please share your suggestions if there is any.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As of now, TV emulator arm64 image is not available for M1. Google team is still working on it to provide support soon. Many developers are waiting for it, only option for now is to check on AndroidTv physical device.

Check this official link, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/203238268?pli=1