# Apple M1 - Your CPU does not support VT-x

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I tried everything and I am running out of ideas to have an Android simulator working on my mac.

---

- I downloaded —again— Android studio from the official website https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

```
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8309675, built on March 16, 2022
```

- I downloaded "the R API Level 30 image"
- I installed "The Zulu OpenJDK" with

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
brew install --cask zulu11
```

- I know the [`android-emulator-m1-preview`](https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview) is not required anymore

---

**Edit:**
Following @mmBs advice, I changed the path to Gradle

```
Preferences > Build > Gradle > Gradle JDK > azul-11
```

[image: gradle JDK]

...same result.

I can't make the virtual device works on my machine.

[image]

I always have this device manager error when I try to launch the simulator.

[image]

**Question:**

How can I have an android simulator working with an Apple M1?

Answer (score 3):

What works for me:

1. Install Android Studio from the official webpage for M1 processors and then install Android SDK in default location `~/Library/Android/sdk`.
2. Install java using brew - brew install openjdk@11 (android supports java 11, no needs for installing java 17 etc.) and then add it to the path.
3. Set your android paths in zsh or bash:

```
# Path to Android SDK
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/ndk-bundle:$PATH"
```

4. Install the emulator image for arm --> arm64-v8a (from Android Studio's Device Manager).
5. Done - it should be working. I use M1 processor and the emulator works just fine. You don't need any m1-emulator-preview from github.

Edit: you can check this thread as well: [Android Studio/Emulator on macOS with ARM CPU M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64907154/android-studio-emulator-on-macos-with-arm-cpu-m1)

Comment: Same error 

I created a new project and I don't know if it's related to this error

```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.
```

Comment: Yeap, so you have an answer --> `Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.` You need to check your path for you project.
1. click 'cmd + ;' to open the a project structure.   
2. Go to sdk location --> Gradle settings.   
3. Choose gradle jdk (you can choose bundled jdk 11 from android studio).  
4. click ok and it should be set.

Comment: making progress here `09:41 Gradle build finished in 638 ms` but my main problem remains Android studio refuses to boot the virtual device —thanks for the input question edited

Comment: ok, what emulator version did you install? Also, did you install HAXM? If yes, you should uninstall it.

Comment: Btw  have you checked this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64907154/android-studio-emulator-on-macos-with-arm-cpu-m1

Comment: Yes that was my starting point before posting here
—I tried all Android ARM Images `arm64-v8a` from 10 to 12

Comment: `Intel_HAXM` was already removed, doubled checked with

https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-macOS#Removing_Intel_HAXM

thank you for your support —I will give up on this

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me!!!
Preferences->Appearance&Behavior->Android SDK->SDK Tools
Check these..see pics
[image]

Comment: For some reason I do not see this Emulator Accelerator option, I'm on MacOS 14, M2 Pro chip, Android Studio electric eel

Answer (score 0):

### 2024 Up to date solution

Android emulator is now **compatible** with arm processor out of the box.

But when you create a new emulator, **not all** emulator and system images in the list are `arm` compatible. Make sure you make the right choice (see screenshot above)

[image]