# Unable to boot and run android emulator on MacBook Air Apple M2 processor with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0, macos-sonoma, apple-m2

This is my configuration:

1. MacBook Air: Apple M2 Memory: 8 Gb MacOs: Sonoma 14.1
2. Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2

    Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10811636, built on September 15, 2023
   Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231 aarch64
   VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o. GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation Memory: 1280M Cores: 8 Metal Rendering is ON

I downloaded the android emulator
Pixel 2 API 31 (Android 12.0 Google play|arm 64)

ERROR: 
The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_31 has terminated.
[image]

and
**Troubleshoot**

Unfortunately, your computer does not support hardware accelerated virtualization. Here are some of your options: 
1) Use a physical device for testing
2) Develop on a Windows/OSX computer with an Intel processor that supports VT-x and NX 
3) Develop on a Linux computer that supports VT-x or SVM 
4) Use an Android Virtual Device based on an ARM system image (This is 10x slower than hardware accelerated virtualization)

Please suggest how I can fix it to run android emulator on my system with android studio for development purpose.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64907154/android-studio-emulator-on-macos-with-arm-cpu-m1

Comment: @MãĴď ... savior

Comment: Ofc happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Our environments are almost the same, but the Mac OS X versions are different.

[image]

It works on my Apple M2.  I use arm64-v8a.
I have the same version of Android Studio as yours.

[image]

But my Mac OS X version is 13.5.
[image]

This is the only different thing I can find for you.
I hope this information can give you more helpful input.

By the way, there is more detailed information in the following.
[image]

Click the `Copy properties to clipboard` and I can see.

```
Properties
avd.ini.displayname              Pixel 2 API 31
avd.ini.encoding                 UTF-8
AvdId                            Pixel_2_API_31
disk.dataPartition.size          6442450944
fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile
fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot no
fastboot.forceColdBoot           no
fastboot.forceFastBoot           yes
hw.accelerometer                 yes
hw.arc                           false
hw.audioInput                    yes
hw.battery                       yes
hw.camera.back                   virtualscene
hw.camera.front                  emulated
hw.cpu.ncore                     4
hw.device.hash2                  MD5:55acbc835978f326788ed66a5cd4c9a7
hw.device.manufacturer           Google
hw.device.name                   pixel_2
hw.dPad                          no
hw.gps                           yes
hw.gpu.enabled                   yes
hw.gpu.mode                      auto
hw.initialOrientation            Portrait
hw.keyboard                      yes
hw.lcd.density                   420
hw.lcd.height                    1920
hw.lcd.width                     1080
hw.mainKeys                      no
hw.ramSize                       1536
hw.sdCard                        yes
hw.sensors.orientation           yes
hw.sensors.proximity             yes
hw.trackBall                     no
image.androidVersion.api         31
image.sysdir.1                   system-images/android-31/google_apis_playstore/arm64-v8a/
PlayStore.enabled                true
runtime.network.latency          none
runtime.network.speed            full
showDeviceFrame                  yes
skin.dynamic                     yes
tag.display                      Google Play
tag.id                           google_apis_playstore
vm.heapSize                      228
```